# Upload XML Files in Django, Parse XML & Compare with existing models dataset

Tags: python, django, xml, database

Can someone give me a better approach for below use case please ?

1. upload XML file
2. Scan XML file with specific tags
3. Store required data in which format ? (I thought of building JSON dump ?)
4. I have data in different models for different components.
5. How can i compare data that i have in step3 with django models and produce some output ? ( Sort of data comparison )

Note : JSON Dump which i get at step 3 is full dump of required data and data at step 4 is being referred to small small chunks of data which has to be combined and compared against recently uploaded file JSON Dump

Answer (score 0):

1. I would define a Model where you can store the uploaded file and a form.
   (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model)
2. Either use lxml etree or generateDS to scan XML Files. (https://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html)
3. To store you can use a JSON-Dump or a Picklefield where you can store the Object of the XML-File in it, if you use generateDS
4. Store the data in a the Database and write a model for it in Django. Try to make it as granular as possible so you can compare the new XML-File when you import it and maybe only store the difference as Objects with Pickle.

Hope that helps a bit.